# Не работает кнопка в сообщении на email

Tags: golang

```
package actions

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "startpage/startserver"

    "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
    "gopkg.in/gomail.v2"
)

type Mail struct {
    Recipient      string `json:"recipient"`
    SenderDomain   string `json:"senderdomain"`
    SenderPort     int    `json:"senderport"`
    SenderMail     string `json:"sendermail"`
    SenderPassword string `json:"senderpassword"`
    Message        []byte `json:"message"`
}

var (
    SENDER_DOMAIN = "smtp-mail.outlook.com"
    SENDER_PORT   = 587
    SENDER_MAIL   = "some@outlook.com"
    SENDER_PASSWORD  = "somepassword"
    RECIPIENT     = "some@mail.ru"
)
//Создаю json в котором будуь все данные для создания и отправки сообщения
func BuildNewMessage(dialer_domain, sender_mail, sender_password, recipient string, dialer_port int) []byte {
    messageJSON := Mail{}
    messageJSON.Recipient = recipient
    messageJSON.SenderDomain = dialer_domain
    messageJSON.SenderPort = dialer_port
    messageJSON.SenderMail = sender_mail
    messageJSON.SenderPassword = sender_password
    messageJSON.Message = BuildHTML(startserver.StaticFiles + "new_password.html")
    marsh, err := json.Marshal(messageJSON)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil
    }
    return marsh
}

//читаю html файл и возрващаю разметку
func BuildHTML(filenamepath string) []byte {
    body, err := ioutil.ReadFile(filenamepath)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        return nil
    }
    return body
}

//Создаю и отправляю почту
func SendMail(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    dataJSON := Mail{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(BuildNewMessage(SENDER_DOMAIN, SENDER_MAIL, SENDER_PASSWORD, RECIPIENT, SENDER_PORT), &dataJSON)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Error(err)
        return
    }
    mes := gomail.NewMessage()
    mes.SetHeader("From", dataJSON.SenderMail)
    mes.SetHeader("To", dataJSON.Recipient)
    mes.SetBody("text/html", string(dataJSON.Message))
    dialer := gomail.NewDialer(dataJSON.SenderDomain, dataJSON.SenderPort, dataJSON.SenderMail, dataJSON.SenderPassword)
    err = dialer.DialAndSend(mes)
    log.Println(err)
}
```

Вот разметка которую я вернул  функцией BuildHTML()

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/.config/usingYaml/templates/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" , name="newpass">
        <input type="text" name="newpasselse">
        <button formaction="http://localhost:8282/new_password/" formmethod="post">Works</button>
        <!-- Да, пост запрос делается на локалхост, так как тестирование происходит именно на локалхосте и если делать запрос на белый ip то будет сбрасывать соединение.-->
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Вот обработчик события когда пользователь из письма на почте нажимает кнопку Works из html

```
router.HandleFunc("/new_password/",
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            log.Println("user typed new password in his email")
            //здесь будет другой код. Это для упрощения вопроса.
        }).Methods(http.MethodPost)
```

Я вижу так: Письмо должно отправиться на почту, пользователь заходит в письмо, заполняет формы и нажимает кнопку Works. После чего происходит запрос на мой сервер по посту и выводится лог что пользователь ввел данные в форму в сообщении на почте.

По факту происходит следующее: письмо на почту приходит, все отображается корректно, но при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.

Что сделать чтобы при нажатии кнопки в письме, происходил запрос на мой сервер и выводился лог.

UPD: Тест делаю в клиенте Evilution

UPD2: Но и в браузере так же.

UPD3: Поменял локалхост в html на белый ip на котором мой сервер и протестировал на смартфоне с мобильных данных. Возникет таймаут.

Comment: Смотрели содержимое html страницы письма? Есть большая вероятность, что почтовый сервер просто напросто вырезает адрес из формы

Comment: правой кнопкой в браузере - открыть inspect - перейти в networks, посмотреть какие запросы отправляются, когда нажимаешь на кнопку отправить. также посмотри на consoles. вдруг там ошибки

Comment: @SeniorPomidor сделал отправку ссылки с токеном. Слишком уж ненадежно внутри письма кнопку делать))

Comment: @ЕвгенийГаврилов сделал отправку ссылки с токеном. Слишком уж ненадежно внутри письма кнопку делать))